# Vue router types act like they are missing after I install vue router in a typescript tutorial project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-2019, vue-router

I'm trying to follow this Vue + okta + Typescriupt tutorial.

I'm to the part where we add the router in src/router/index.ts.

in Vs2019, I get a red underline under Vue.Use(Router);

here is the code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ '../views/Home.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/search',
            name: 'search',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ '../views/Search.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/details',
            name: 'details',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "details" */ '../views/Details.vue')
        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

This implies that the types are missing to me.

if I hover over it, I get [image]

According to to the Vue Router docs, once I do "npm install vue-router" to install vue router, I should already have the types, which I did(3.4.9 was installed).

If run it npm run serve, the apps seems to work.

How do I fix the issue that Vs2019 is showing?

Comment: Not sure about VS2019 but in VSCode there's an option to switch to the in-project version of Typescript so you should Google if you can do that. This will enable you to switch to a newer TS version that you can install with `npm install typescript --save-dev`.
Seems like Vue-router package already has all of the types built in so ignore the following

~~~But, I think that the main culprit here could be that you could actually be missing the types so try installing them manually as a dev dependency with `npm install @types/vue-router --save-dev` and then reload your project.~~~

Comment: @types/vue-router is depreciated https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vue-router